# Prevent insert data into table at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, insert

I'm working on a online sales web site. I'm using C# 4,0 and SQL server 2008 and I want to control  and prevent users simultaneously insert into the table like dbo.orders... How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean ordering a specific item simultaneously? Do you want to maintain remained items consistent?

Comment: Why is it a problem that users add orders at the same time?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to limit concurrent inserts? SQL Server should cope with multiple inserts through its own locking mechanisms, and there are techniques for avoiding resource contention too e.g. [from sqlcat.com](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2009/09/22/resolving-pagelatch-contention-on-highly-concurrent-insert-workloads-part-1.aspx)

Comment: ok... thank you people... im designing a website first time and just wondering is there a problem even 100s multiple insert or update if there is a problem how to solve... question was wrong sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

In your Add method you can use Locking with lock keyword, this will allow one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Inserts will not be a problem, but updates can be.  The term that you need to research is database concurrency.  There are four basic models you can implement each with its own pros and cons.  Some are better suited for certain situations and there are hundreds of articles on the web for this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to solve this in C# code on in SQL? Because in SQL it's simple. If you add BEGIN TRAN in the beginning of the stored procedure and COMMIT in the end, this will act as a lock in C# preventing concurrent code executions effectively serializing the requests. So if there are two inserts, they will be executed one after another. One thing to remember is that it will be blocking operation, i.e. the second insert won't start until the first one is finished (regardless successfully or not).